# Spring-boot failing to connect to mysql container even after supplying proper mysql service name

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

This might sound repeated question but it is not and this is a crazy bug I feel, however, let me quickly explain my setup:

A simple Spring bootstrap application that runs pretty well on my local and JDBC connection string in `application.properites` file is as follows.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://minesql:3306/datamachine?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
```

The docker running instances are:
[image]

I copied (with the help of `docker cp` command) the war file to alpine (unix container) and running it in interactive mode to test and it is throwing exception as it is unable to ping the mysql server. I am certain that the database configurations are fine and clueless why the springboot app is failing to connect to mysql container instance. Note, the mysql container does have "datamachine" database created manually.

This is the error reported:
[image]

Please help me understand what I am missing here or what is going wrong.

Just in-case if you wish to know how I started these containers.

For mysql:

```
docker run -d --name minesql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=**** -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Running Java app from the alpine container and this is how I am starting the alpine,

```
docker run -it --name unix alpine
```

The interactive mode present me the `bash` prompt to run the spring-boot war file. (..and running the war file after installing the java 8 in alpine)

Comment: How are you starting the containers?

Comment: @Wander3r Thanks for reading through. Please find the updated question to answer your specific query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two docker containers which are running and connected via default bridge network. From docker bridge [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by
> IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered
> legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each
> other by name or alias.

If you need the second container to be able to resolve the name `minesql` from inside, you need to create a user-defined network bridge and connect the docker container containers to that.

Create a new network using

```
docker network create my-net
```

And add your containers as specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-a-user-defined-bridge)

Other alternative is to use docker-compose and avoid manual creation of bridge networks for name resolution. For production environment, that would be ideal.